# styling the shadow dom :after using next sibling in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

OK take this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>Lorem
       :after
    </p>
</div>
```

this can be styled like so:

```
 .foo p:after{
   content: 'ipsum';
   display: block;
  }
```

Now i have a dynamically added form into the p using javascript like so:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>Lorem
        <form action="POST">
            <input type="text" />
            <button>SEND</button>
        </form>
       :after
    </p>
</div>
```

but I can't style the form using a adjacent pseudo selector like so:

```
 .foo p >form + *:after{
   content: 'ipsum';
   display: block;
  }
```

why not? 
and how do i style the :After only if it's next to the form?
Chris

Comment: A `<p>` element can only contain inline elements. Form is block level and it's going to cause problems. I changed it to a div and it looks good to me, see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rgwut/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to style **::after pseudo-elements of elements that are direct siblings to the form element, which is a direct child of p element which is a child of .foo**. All other conditions match, but there is no direct sibling for a `form` element in your structure.

In order to style p::after in case where there are form elements as children, you'd need to have a parent selector, which practically doesn't exist. According to the spec the rule would look like:

```
!form > p::after { ... }
```

Comment: so the :after isn't considered a sibling elemet?

Comment: As far as I've understood: it's a pseudo-element, not a sibling element as such.